# Serilog writes the logs twice

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, serilog, kibana-6

I'm using `Serilog` with Elasticsearch sink with the configurations like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
                    .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                    .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails()
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("Application", "abc")
                    .Enrich.WithProperty("Environment", env.EnvironmentName)
                    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(Configuration["LoggingEndpoint"]))
                    {
                        AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
                        CustomFormatter = new ExceptionAsObjectJsonFormatter(renderMessage: true) // Better formatting for exceptions
                    })
```

// and later:

```
services.AddLogging(loggingBuilder =>
            loggingBuilder.AddSerilog());
```

But I can see every log twice, with a couple of milliseconds difference in their timestamp, on the Kibana. I tried the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48782853/avoid-logging-twice-using-netcore2-0-on-aws-lambda-with-serilog), just in case they might help, but no luck.

Comment: What did you to resolve this?

Comment: Perhaps a bit late. But did you also configure the serilog logging inside your appsettings.json? If so it will log from code and from logging. I had some problem!

Comment: Jordy's response should be the answer

Comment: @JordyvanEijk did you find any solution to this? I use SerilogRequestLogging and if I have an exception in my controller it's being logged two times.

Comment: @jmazur do you still have this problem? Maybe you log your exception inside the controller and rethrow it and it will be catched by your application itself?

Answer (score 15):

This is probably the case because you are configuring Serilog inside your appsettings.json and also inside code. This wil Log everything twice.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly the case in my code. I was using WriteTo(new JsonFormatter()) and right after it ReadFrom.Configuration. I removed the latter and now it logs properly.